# Cannot resolve file in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rubymine

I am trying to use RubyMine (v6.3.3) for my rails project. 
After I added `bootstrap-sass` gem according its instruction
in https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass, RubyMine complains about the line I added in `application.js` file. However the file is actually in the scope of the projects' external libraries.

The project itself works as expected, just this RubyMine warning annoyed me.

Did I miss any step in configuration?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is confirmed to be a RubyMine issue.

`bootstrap-sass` gem has added `assets` to the assets path, and that's why the project works. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/lib/bootstrap-sass/engine.rb#L6

However RubyMine appeares to ignore the `Rails.application.config.asset.paths` setting and only inspect the default asset paths. That's why the red wavy underline appears.

Here is the open issue for RubyMine: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-15585

The workaround to this is to create a symbol link (vendor/assets -> assets) in your local gem installation. It will shut RubyMine up.

```
2.1.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.2.0.0% ls -l vendor
total 8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 gogao  staff  9 Aug  7 11:28 assets -> ../assets
```

More details can be found in the GitHub issue https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/684 (Thank you, @Ri4a)

Answer (score 3):

It's a problem with the `bootstrap-sass` gem. See here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/684

Comment: @jeroenvisser101: yes, see the accepted answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Use `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` instead of `//= require bootstrap_sprockets` in application.js

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. I was experimenting. And I have just updated the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here, it seems that rubymine does not recognises the libraries stored in `vendor/assets/components`. If you store your library in `vendor/assets/javascripts` or in `app/assets/javascripts`, it will be recognized by rubymine.

Answer (score 0):

I try many methods, but they don't work for me.

At last, I fixed it using a strange method:

1. Quit RubyMine
2. cd /path/your_rails_project
3. rm -r .idea/
4. Restart RubyMine and open your project

The related environment in my case:

RubyMine: 7.1

bootstrap-sass: 3.3.4

I hope this answer would save other guys' time.