# Rails 4 Bootstrap 3 dataTables can't find copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I have a Rails 4 app using Bootstrap 3 and the `gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'`.

This is my javascript:

```
  $("#dataTable1").dataTable
    bfilter: true
    bLengthChange: true
    scrollY:        "300px"
    paging: false
    oColVis:
      buttonText: "Hide/Show"
      bRestore: true
    sDom: "C<\"clear\">lfrTtiXp"
    oTableTools:
      aButtons: [
        "xls"
      ,
        sExtends: "pdf"
        sPdfOrientation: "landscape"
        sPdfMessage: "pdf"
        mColumns: "visible"
      ]
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://burtondav.myevdata.dev/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf
```

The file is in the external libraries:

[image]

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE1

This is my application.js:

```
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.tableTools
//= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.colVis
//= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.colReorder
//= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.keyTable
//= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.responsive
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
```

And application.css:

```
 *= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
 *= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.tableTools
 *= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.colVis
 *= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.colReorder
 *= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.keyTable
 *= require dataTables/extras/dataTables.responsive
```

Comment: Have you setup the `application.js` and `application.css` files correctly? https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails#general-installation

Comment: What version of 'jquery-datatables-rails' are you using? 2.2.3 has some breaking upgrades.  I think I'll post a reference as an answer for you.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Did you ever make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I just converted from jquery-datatables-rails 2.2.1 to 2.2.3 to get to DataTables 1.10.2.  I found some breaking issues in that conversion, especially related to variable names.  DataTables 1.10 renamed many of its variables, but provides backward compatible support to 1.9.  However, jquery-datatables-rails does not maintain that backward compatibility.

I noticed you are using the old naming conventions. I didn't experience the specific problem that you mentioned, but I did find many others and may have just not hit this one.  So, if you are using 2.2.3, which I would recommend, please reference [Upgrading to jquery-datatables-rails 2.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169803/upgrade-to-jquery-datatables-rails-2-2-3-from-2-2-1-breaks-code-in-railscasts-34/26170301#26170301).

There is another possible answer here.  From the image you provided, it looks like you are using RubyMine.  I'm at 6.3.3 and there is a known problem with a fix developed but not yet released.  Reference [Cannot resolve file in RubyMine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646244/cannot-resolve-file-in-rubymine/24646383#24646383).  Also, this is the [JetBrains issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-15585).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

swf never worked for me with bootstrap. I attempted with bootstrap 2 and recently with bootstrap 3. So, I removed the bootstrap styling using the data tables default styling provided by  and VOILA! The swf showed up in above or below my table, depending of my dom.

Comment: I removed this line `"sPaginationType": "bootstrap"` and Rails still can't find the file.  Is that the right step?

Comment: I also removed `//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap` and `*= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap` - still have the same issue.

Comment: I set jqueryUI=false and used Bootstrap styling which resolved many/most of my problems but not all.